# Kali 2.0 - No DSL configuration

Tags: networking, kali-linux, dsl

I booted Kali from USB in order to install it, I was all hyped up about it, but I bumped into this big problem: when I go to Settings → network I click the "+" sign to add a new connection there's no option to add a DSL connection, there's just VPN, Bridge, Team, VLAN.

Also I tried each of them to see if there is an option for a DSL connection, obviously there wasn't. I'd love if anyone could show me how to configure a DSL connection in Kali 2.0.

Comment: on top of start menu bar click on wired connection icon ,add new profile with ur dsl ip,you would be able to configure it

Comment: I accidentally approved `Rishi Khandelwal`'s edit.  The edit is actually invalid and should not be approved.

Comment: Have you tried the command `ip link set dev eth0 up`?

Answer (score 1):

At last i found the solution to your and mine problem. 
1.Open terminal 
2.Type nm-connection-editor
3. click ADD
4. DSL 
5. .....

done
here you get your connection on.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I'll check to see if it works, but I managed to find a router that way I didn't need to add a DSL connection.